# Computation of a Residue (Complex Analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have attempted to compute this residue:

$g(z) = \frac{e^z − 1}{z^3} $ at $z = 0$

and I found that:

$\frac{e^z -1}{z^3} =\frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{2! z} + \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{z}{4!} + \ldots $

So I concluded that the residue is $1/6$, but the apparent answer is $1/2$ and I'm not sure why.

Could anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: You really need to be more careful: apparently you meant to write $\;\frac{e^z-1}{z^3}\;$ , yet you did write $\;e^z-\frac1{z^3}\;$ ..

Comment: The residue is not the constant coefficient from the power series, but the one from $1/z$, because that is the only term that does not vanish under a contour integral.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^z-1 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{z^n}{n!}\tag{1}$$
implies:
$$ \frac{e^z-1}{z^3} = \frac{1}{z^2}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2! z}}+\frac{1}{3!}+\ldots \tag{2}$$
hence:
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^z-1}{z^3},z=0\right) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2!}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: thanks a lot, I get it now!